# CORS that require preflight, using passport, express angularjs

Tags: angularjs, express, cors

I am currently implementing an app that uses express and passport on the server side. Every time a user tries to log in, the passport authenticate is activated, having two parameters - `successRedirect` and `failureRedirect`.

```
app.post('/login',
   passport.authenticate('local', {
   successRedirect: '/',
   failureRedirect: '/login',
 })
);
```

I have the following headers

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  next();
});
```

My server has URL : http://localhost:9998
And the application is on : http://localhost:9000
Whenever I get to the place `successRedirect` has to be rendered I get the following error :

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:9998/login. The request was redirected to 'http://localhost:9998/', which is disallowed for cross-origin requests that require preflight.
```

Comment: does `/login` implement the HTTP `OPTIONS` method?  I believe that it is absolutely required for CORS pre-flight.

Comment: Have you confirmed that your app is definitely returning the desired headers? If you make a test `OPTIONS` call to your app, does it work for an *unauthenticated* user? If not, that's the problem.

Comment: It doesn't work for unauthenticated users. But i currently don't have OPTIONS method implemented.

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of pre-flight requests in most browsers mean said browser issuing an `OPTIONS` request, so if the site doesn't respond to those, the request will fail (note also that the request must be open, it can't require authentication).